# Convert time (given in days since YYYY) into readable time format

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, converters

I need help with converting time to a readable format. My `time` array (has 580 elements) is # of days since January 1st, 1900. How do I convert that to a normal time format (ie mm-dd-yyyy)?

For example, input time is 43,887 and output should read 02-27-2020 after adding it to Jan 1, 1900.

Thank you!

Comment: `43887` is not equal to `02-27-2020` but `1970-01-01`.

Comment: @CodePope err... actually 1900-01-01 + 43,887 days is 2020-02-28...

Comment: Try using date.add() add your number to jan 1 1900. You should now have a datetime that you can use time.ctime() to make a string.

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` and `timedelta` class can be helpful here.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def convert(inp, date1):
    new_date = date1 + timedelta(inp)
    return new_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

date1 = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
print(convert(43887, date1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datetime.datetime class can help you here. The following works, if those values are treated as integer days (you don't specify what they are).

```
   from datetime import datetime
   dt = datetime.fromordinal(43887)
   dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```